# John the Ripper modify passwords before checking

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

Assume I have a password I want to crack in the following format:

- 100 times the character 'a' prepended to
- Some word found in a wordlist

John will probably not be able to crack this with the default configuration. Is there a way to tell it to do something with a password (in this case, prepend 'aaaaaa...') before checking for its validity?

Comment: create a wordlist with the combinations you want and feed that to jtr

Comment: @schroeder hmm I guess that is a way to do it.. thank you